# Appending String to end of URL - Beginner

Tags: grails

I have a method where i am redirecting it to another action. Here's the code:

```
def redirectPage (String appNum) {
    redirect(action: "showMan")
}
```

Now, once this the navigates to another page the URL will appear as `http://myserver/myapp/showMan`

I want this URL to appear as `http://myserver/myapp/showMan?SomeIdentifier`

I actually want to append this ID to the end of the page `?SomeIdentifier` . How can i do it?

Comment: Which id? How should the URL look like in the end? If request parameters are added then it is represented as key value pair, for example, `redirect(action: "showMan", params: [someId: 1])` will give an URL as `http://myserver/myapp/showMan?someId=1`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `param` attribute of `redirect` according to the official [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html).

```
redirect(action: 'showMan', params: [param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'])
```

This will result in

```
http://<host>/<your-app>/<controller>/showMan?param1=value1&param2=value2
```